# How to use With inside a ContourPlot in mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to use something like:

ContourPlot [Abs[z-1] == 2]

and to define z as being = x + iy

I saw somewhere an example like that with the With function, but I can't find it anymore and all my tries are not being successful.

Comment: I doubt he does, since Contour isn't a standard Mathematica function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. You just need to be sure to either put the `With` outside of the `ContourPlot`:

```
With[{z = x + I y},
   ContourPlot[Abs[z - 1] == 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]]
```

You can also use `Evaluate`:

```
ContourPlot[
  With[{z = x + I y}, Abs[z - 1] == 2] // Evaluate, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

This is generally the case with plotting functions, which almost always evaluate their arguments in a non-standard way.